# Set uuid on page load using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I am new to javascript I am trying to set the uuid as a value of my textfield on page load however I am getting error val property null but code will work when I associate it with button lister but I wanted to implement it on page load

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
   function guid() {
  return "ss-s-s-s-sss".replace(/s/g, s4);
}

function s4() {
  return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
    .toString(16)
    .substring(1);
}


  document.getElementById('value').value = guid();

        </script>
```

Comment: It's probable the element isn't loaded when the script is run. Place it just above your `body` closing tag.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try to replace

```
function guid() {
  return "ss-s-s-s-sss".replace(/s/g, s4);
}
```

with

function guid() {

```
  return "ss-s-s-s-sss".replace(/s/g, s4());
}
```

Comment: That will make it non-random; he wants to pass the function itself.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Comment: Thanks for new knowledge, I din`t know about this. I thought only string could be pasted as second param.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add load event listener on window.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function {
  document.getElementById('value').value = guid();
})
```